# how to distribute the data aggregation work to multiple spark executors

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

need quick suggestion.

I have a compressed file in S3 (3 GB size), and I am trying to read that file using apache spark and then I am performing aggregation operations.

so when I launch the spark job with below configurations

```
--num-executors 3 --executor-memory 10G --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 5G
```

spark job started with 3 executors but only one task is getting launched and other 2 executors are ideal. I tried doing `reparation(3)`

just to insist the spark to launch more tasks but I still see only one task running. in my current scenario, the data side is 50 G when it is uncompressed, and since only one task is trying to process the data, I am seeing out of memory exception.

I have tried adding StorageLevel, but that didn't solve my issue.

any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which compression you are using in s3? what kind of aggregation you are doing?

Comment: What are the values of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` `spark.default.parallelism`?  Try to get those values from spark context in your job and log them.